Selecting a uniform distribution type from the standard library
Summary:  Given a numeric type T, is there a concise way to declare a variable as either std::uniform_int_distribution<T> or std::uniform_real_distribution<T> depending upon whether T is integral or floating point?

I needed to produce random std::chrono::durations uniformly distributed over a caller-defined range, so I created a uniform_duration_distribution class template modeled after that standard library's distribution class templates.
First I wrote a concept to constrain my distribution to a chrono duration (or suitably similar type).
// Is T similar enough to std::chrono::duration for our purposes?
template <typename T>
concept chrono_duration = requires (T d) {
    { d.count() } -> std::same_as<typename T::rep>;
    { d.zero()  } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { d.max()   } -> std::same_as<T>;
};

A duration has a numeric representation called a count.  My class contains a numeric uniform distribution from the standard library, uses it to generate a count, and constructs a duration from that count.
template<chrono_duration DurationT>
class uniform_duration_distribution {
  // ...
  private:
    using rep = typename DurationT::rep;
    std::uniform_distribution<rep> m_distribution;  // Whoops!
};

And therein lies the problem.  The type of the duration's count can be either an integral type or a floating point type, so the type of m_distribution isn't as simple as std::uniform_distribution<T> because there is no such template.
I didn't want to make several specializations of my class, and I didn't want limit callers to one specific instantiation of a duraiton.  I just wanted to choose the type for the contained distribution based on the duration's rep type.
My first attempt was to use a type alias template restricted by concepts.
template <std::integral IntT>
using dist_selector = std::uniform_int_distribution<IntT>;

template <std::floating_point FloatT>
using dist_selector = std::uniform_real_distribution<FloatT>;

This doesn't seem to be allowed.  I can (apparently) constrain a single using alias template with a concept, but I cannot use concepts to select between different aliases.  At least, not as I tried it.  Is there a way to do so?
I also learned I cannot specialize using alias templates.
In the end I made a struct template with specializations for the numeric types.
// Select the appropriate distribution type based on the value type.
template <typename T> struct dist_selector {};
template <> struct dist_selector<long double>        { using t = std::uniform_real_distribution<long double>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<double>             { using t = std::uniform_real_distribution<double>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<float>              { using t = std::uniform_real_distribution<float>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<long long>          { using t = std::uniform_int_distribution<long long>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<long>               { using t = std::uniform_int_distribution<long>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<int>                { using t = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<short>              { using t = std::uniform_int_distribution<short>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<unsigned long long> { using t = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long long>; };
template <> struct dist_selector<unsigned long>      { using t = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long>; };
// ...

Then the member variable is defined as:
using rep = typename DurationT::rep;
using dist_type = typename dist_selector<rep>::t;
dist_type m_distribution;

This works but feels like falling back to an old hack.  Am I missing a more modern way to do this?

How are you going to initialize the distribution? Assuming it's a small enough range [a,b], you'll need to initialize uniform_int_distribution with a,b and uniform_real_distribution with a,nextafter(b,max). And then in generation, for uniform_real_distribution, you'll have to repeatedly generate to discard >b to workaround a common bug. So it's not just the type that's different. It probably deserves it's own distribution type, or at least a traits type.

You can use a class template for the specialization via the concepts, then add the alias template for convenience:
#include <random>
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> struct dist_selector;

template <typename T> requires std::integral<T>
struct dist_selector<T> {
     using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>; 
};

template <typename T> requires std::floating_point<T>
struct dist_selector<T> { 
    using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>; 
};

template <typename T>
using dist_selector_t = dist_selector<T>::type;


int main () {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::uniform_int_distribution<int>,dist_selector_t<int>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::uniform_real_distribution<float>,dist_selector_t<float>>);
}

Live Demo
Alternatively you can use std::conditional:
template <typename T>
using dis_sel = std::conditional_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>,
                            std::type_identity<std::uniform_real_distribution<T>>,
                            std::type_identity<std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>>::type;

Live Demo
Note how std::type_identity avoids to ask for the ::type member alias that does not exist (eg std::type_identity<std::uniform_int_distribution<double>> is an "ok" type, it just has no type member alias).

Ah, a hybrid of the things I tried.  I didn't see that.  Thanks!  I haven't studied std::type_identity yet, but I'll look into that as well.

I'd start with a type trait / concept to constrain the template parameter to be of a std::chrono::duration type:
template<class>
struct is_duration : std::false_type {};

template<class Rep, class Period>
struct is_duration<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>> : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
concept chrono_duration = is_duration<T>::value;

Then a distribution selector could look like this, where an instance of T must match one of the contrained test functions:
template<class T>
struct distribution_selector {
    template<class I>
        requires std::integral<I>
    static auto test(I) -> std::uniform_int_distribution<I>;

    template<class F>
        requires std::floating_point <F>
    static auto test(F) -> std::uniform_real_distribution<F>;

    using type = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()));
};

template<class T>
using distribution_selector_t = distribution_selector<T>::type;

Putting it together:
template<chrono_duration DurationT>
class uniform_duration_distribution {
public:
    using rep = DurationT::rep;

    distribution_selector_t<rep> m_distribution;
};

Demo

Yeah, that works, and you taught me stuff.  It seems a bit roundabout, though, to declare the test functions to get the type of its return.  While that is a little shorter, I'm not sure it's easier for the reader to see what's going on compared to the tedious list of specializations I had.

@AdrianMcCarthy It's just one of many ways to do it, and it's been used quite a lot since C++11 came out. You can declare a class and make specializations of that class for floats and ints instead which is essentially doing the same thing. Both are easier to maintain than a list of all the current ints and floats I'd say.

I up-voted this—I always learn from your posts!—but I think the constraints could be a little tighter. (1) std::is_integral allows character and boolean types, as well as extended integral types, but those are disallowed (i.e., "undefined") by std::uniform_int_distribution. (2) std::is_floating_point allows extended floating-point types, but those are disallowed (i.e., "undefined") by std::uniform_real_distribution. (continued...)

(3) Both std::is_integral and std::is_floating_point allow cv-qualified types, but those are disallowed (i.e., "undefined") by the distributions in <random>. See CppReference here and here.

@tbxfreeware Yeah, that's true. One could tighten it up to not get odd compilation errors or worse, ub, if used with a duration that uses any of those types.
